# Is this sequence Cauchy given this $\max$ norm?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

> In $C[0,1]$ with $$\|f\| := \max_{[0,1]} |f(x)|$$ is $f_n (x) = x^n$, for $n=1,\dots, \infty$, a Cauchy sequence?

---

Suppose I have a big positive natural number N, and any m , n > N. Then I need to study $$ \|f_m - f_n\| = \|x^m - x^n\| = \max_{[0,1]} |x^m - x^n| $$ Then how can I know whether it is small than $\epsilon$ or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not a Cauchy sequence. If it was, then there would be some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that if $m,n\geqslant N$, then $\max|x^m-x^n|\leqslant\frac12$. But then, since the $\lim_{m\to\infty}\bigl|x^m-x^N\bigr|$ exists when $x\in[0,1)$, we have$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\bigl|x^m-x^N\bigr|\leqslant\frac12;\quad\text{in other words,}\quad x^N\leqslant\frac12,$$for every $x\in[0,1)$, since in this interval we have $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^m=0$. But this is impossible, since $\lim_{x\to1}x^N=1$.

Comment: I don't quite understand the answer from "in other words".

Comment: You have, if $x\in[0,1)$,$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\bigl|x^m-x^N|=|0-x^N|=x^N.$$

Comment: In your last sentence, you say "But this is impossible". Could you tell me why?

Comment: If you have $x^N\leqslant\frac12$ for each $x\in[0,1)$, you cannot have $\lim_{x\to1}x^N=1$.

Comment: The reason that we can say the limit exists (we assume it is Cauchy) is due to with this norm, C[0,1] is a Banach space, so the Cauchy must be convergent. Am I right?

Comment: No. I did not use that at all. The limit $\lim_{m\to\infty}\bigl|x^m-x^N\bigr|$ exists and it is equal to $|-x^N|(=x^N)$ because $\lim_{m\to\infty}x^m=0$ (if $x\in[0,1)$).